# Table with sort android

Tags: android

I need to create table, some like excel and I want to sort elements by headers. Any ideas how can I do that? Use Table Layout or something else? Maybe is some librery when I can find this component?

Comment: What about using listview with custom rows?

Comment: I want to sort by every column in this table. This will be possible in ListView?

Comment: Yes , by using Custom adapters.

Comment: There is any example how can I do that?

Comment: You can import the data into a database, then query the table using the `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use something like this: https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders for the table. In order to do the sorting, this is pretty easy. Simply set OnClickListeners on each view on the top row and change the ordering when each is clicked accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For big data it will be better to make list view with custon list items.